# Start OpenSSH service on iphone from iphone terminal

Tags: iphone, ios, jailbreak, openssh

The OpenSSH ssh daemon is a useful tool for iPhone development.

I use it to connect my MacOS @ my phone quickly.

Is it possible to start the service directly from the terminal, without using some *toggle*?

Comment: Tnks to Nate! On my iPhone works perfectly. launchctl load /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.openssh.sshd.plist it's what i need

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I assume you're using a terminal directly **on the phone**, otherwise how could you get in to turn on the ssh daemon, right?

Anyway, you can use this command to start the service:

```sh
launchctl load /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.openssh.sshd.plist
```

and this one to stop it:

```sh
launchctl unload /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.openssh.sshd.plist
```

Note, that if you use this, and **also** have the SBSettings ssh toggle installed, its state (red=off, green=on) will be out of sync with the actual service.  (You can just tap the SBSettings toggle a couple times, and it will be back in sync again)

Comment: -> `launchctl load /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.openssh.sshd.plist` it's what I was searching 4. "SBSettings ssh toggle installed" it's my best friend I want it forever =green! Red color disturb me!! `launchctl unload /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.openssh.sshd.plist` works also to stop. :) hi Nate!